# Atomic bounded increase in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

`t1`:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | n_data | type |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |     10 |    1 |
+----+--------+------+
```

`t2`:

```
+-----+------+
| type | max |
+------+-----+
|    1 |  50 |
+------+-----+
```

What I would like to do is: when the user selects an element of `t1`, say with `id = 1`, I increase the corresponding `n_data` by 1, except if it has reached the corresponding value `max` in `t2` (with the `join` `t1.type = t2.type`).
In this case, I would warn the user.

What I have:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT t1.n_data, t2.max 
                        FROM t1, t2 
                        WHERE t1.type = t2.type AND t1.id = " . $id);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row["n_data"] < $row["max"]) {
  $conn->query("UPDATE t1 
                SET n_data = n_data + 1 
                WHERE id = " . $id);
}
else {
  echo "We have reached the max!";
}
```

Obviously, I have a race condition here.  Someone else can increase `n_data` between the two MySQL instructions.

How to merge the two queries into one, or make them atomic?

Comment: Your code also looks to be prone for SQL injections..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Very true, I never use string concatenation in my code.  But I find it more concise in this context.

Comment: Also with the current code it also seams to be possible that `n_data` can get `1` higher then the `max` in the `t2` table because off the `$row["n_data"] <= $row["max"]` check.. if n_date = `50` which is lower and equal then `max` = 50 so the update will be executed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland D'oh!  I changed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would update the table with the `max` in the where clause:

```
update t1
set n_data=n_data+1 
where 
  id = :id and
  n_data < :max;
```

After that, you can check affected rows. If it's 0, it means your max was reached and the update failed.

But of course, instead of passing in `max` as a parameter, it's even better to query it inline:

```
update t1
set n_data=n_data+1 
where 
  id = :id and
  n_data < (select max from t2 where t2.type=t1.type);
```

The total PHP code would then be very simple. Just run this update, and after that, check if affected rows == 0 and echo the error message in that case. Something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    update t1
    set n_data=n_data+1
    where 
      id = ? and
      n_data < (select max from t2 where t2.type=t1.type)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute([$id]);

if ($stmt->num_rows === 0) {
  echo "We have reached the max!";
}
```

Comment: The inner select doesn't need the id. It doesn't have it in OP's question either. The id is given. `t2` just contains the max per type, which is why the solution can be way simpler than what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction !

```
START TRANSACTION;

 <your SQL code>

COMMIT;
```

Every transactions are made to be A.C.I.D.
The A means Atomicity. That means that all of the changes will commit in the same time at the end of your transaction.

Your can store your transaction in a stored procedure.

Comment: Great!  But there is PHP code between the 2 SQL queries.  Is it possible to add it inside the transaction?  Otherwise, how to translate the PHP `if` in MySQL?

Comment: Just execute `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` as seperate queries, then you are able to run whatever you like in between

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can translate easily the if statement in the transaction in SQL.